# How to retrieve data from list in SPFX solution

Tags: reactjs, http, sharepoint, spfx, pnp-js

I have 3 components - RequestSHP.tsx, WebPart.ts, Exekucie.tsx
I am trying to get data to dropdown from list, but getting error "404 (Not Found)"

Here is my RequestSHP.tsx ->

```
import {sp} from '@pnp/sp/presets/all';



export default class RequestSHP {
  public async getAreas(listId: string) {
    console.log(listId);
    try {
        return await sp.web.lists.getById('listID').items.get();
    }
    catch (error) {
        throw (`Cannot request [${listId}] -> [${String(error)}]`);
    }
}
}
```

In Webpart component I have ->

```
private async getAreas(listId: string): Promise<string[]> {
  console.log('get aeras', listId);
  let areas: any;
  try {
    areas = await (new RequestSHP()).getAreas(listId);
  }
  catch (err) {
    throw "gAR: " + err;
  }
  return areas;
}

if ("test" === "test") {
      console.log("test");
      (renderForm = NewForm);
    }
    try {
      let resultPrimaryAreas = await this.getAreas(props.selectListPobocka); 
      props = {...props, primaryAreas: resultPrimaryAreas}
      renderForm = NewForm;
      console.log("YES!!!");
    }
    catch (e) {
      error = false;
      this.domElement.innerHTML = 'Error'
     console.log('Error')
    }
```

Now I cannot get list (gettint 404 not found)

What I am missing ?

Comment: Can you check the console window / Network. Check the URL for this failed call

Comment: have you setup/initialize SP context ?

Comment: Refer this - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306064/web-part-works-on-localhost-but-it-does-not-working-on-spo/306067#306067

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the existing comments.

1. You should prove that you initialized correctly the @pnp/sp library by showing the initialization line, which will be different depending on the major version of the pnp library you're using (just follow the instructions on the official documentation: [Getting Started - Pnp/PnPJs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/getting-started/#using-pnpsp-spfi-factory-interface-in-spfx)
2. We do not know what is the value of the `props.selectListPobocka` variable. A good additional information for debugging would be the URL that is called in your Network tab in DevTools. You may then undestand if it is an issue with initialization (as the url should look like `<sp_web_url>/_api/web/lists('<list_guid>')/items`) or with the variable value.

Hope this helps